# Do the figures on /proc/<pid>/io include paging and swapping I/O?

Tags: monitoring, io, swap, proc, virtual-memory

I know that:

- paging and swapping is done to/from the disk
- /proc/io gives information of disk I/O

However, I am not sure if */proc/<pid>/io* includes I/O that was expected to be done on RAM but went to the disk because of paging and swapping. Do the figures on */proc/<pid>/io* include paging and swapping I/O?

Comment: I would doubt it, since it's the kernel doing the reading and writing of the swap, not the process.  But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question, so I decided to perform some experiments with the swap usage and I/O accounting.

I wrote a simple program, that just requests a large amount of memory and fills it with data:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
        void* ptr = malloc(1000000);
        memset(ptr, 42, 1000000);
    }

    // Hang for a while to allow us analyze /proc.
    puts("Finished");
    while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Then I started running it, increasing the amount of the memory requested with every run (5G, 10G, 12G and so on), and watched the process' `/proc/$PID/io` and `/proc/$PID/status`. The following parameters from `/proc/$PID/io` remained the same for every run (and this was expected, as these parameters show *syscall-level* IO statistics):

```
rchar: 1948
wchar: 9
syscr: 7
syscw: 1
```

The next two parameters, which (as per the [kernel procfs documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt#L1593)) show actual disk I/O, caused by the process, were set to zeroes (it's likely that the program image was already cached in the memory from the previous executions, so `execve` did not cause a real disk I/O):

```
read_bytes: 0
write_bytes: 0
```

When I was close to RAM size (16G), the kernel started to swap out program's memory in quite large amounts (~4G):

```
$ cat /proc/$PID/status | grep VmSwap
VmSwap:  3908152 kB
```

At the same time some strange values appeared in `/proc/$PID/io`:

```
read_bytes: 307200
write_bytes: 0
```

Non-zero value of `read_bytes` appeared when the kernel started swapping, and remained almost the same (~300k) while amount of swap used by the process increased with every consequent run (until it started triggering the OOMKiller).

I repeated these experiments a few times, and the picture remained the same: `write_bytes` was zero all the time, and `read_bytes` changed from zero to some small (relatively to the memory amount being swapped) value around 300-400k.

Based on this, I think that `/proc/$PID/io` does not account *actual swap reads and writes*, but it accounts some *internal kernel activities, caused by the swap usage*.